# How to use google Distance Matrix Webservice properly

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

I have tried to use Google Distance Matrix Webservice in PHP.(http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#XML)

From PHP i sent request to that webservice, and try to get response xml.But it returns that xml file not exists. Same url works fine from browser.

**PHP file:**

```
$request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=11.498507+77.245688&destinations=11.497208+77.244656&sensor=false";

if (file_exists($request_url)) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
print_r($xml);
} 
else {
exit('Failed to open request_url.');
}
```

**OutPut :** Failed to open request_url.

How to use the response XMl from the distance matrix webservice properly.

Answer (score 1):

The call to file_exists() returns false. I think this is because file_exists() does not work for remote files, but I am not certain about that. I suggest you make use of [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) like this:

```
$request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=11.498507+77.245688&destinations=11.497208+77.244656&sensor=false";

$content = file_get_contents($request_url);
if (false !== $content) {
    echo $content;
} 
else {
    exit('Failed to retrieve contents from request_url.');
}
```